# AndroidManifest.xml - The element must be a direct child of the <application> element error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

I made a copy of one of my working projects for another project. Ever since I can't get the AndroidManifest.xml to work properly. I get the error `The element must be a direct child of the <application> element` or `The element type "manifest" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</manifest>"`error.  I have refactored everything else and don't see any errors in my classes. Just the xml file is being a pain. What is wrong with this file? It looks fine and looks like my working one. Eclipse seems to think there are errors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package= "com.mydomain.qsd"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.mydomain.qsd.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.mydomain.qsd.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.mydomain.qsd.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mydomain.qsd.SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.mydomain.qsd.gcm.GCMReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.mydomain.qsd" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.mydomain.qsd.gcm.GCMService"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.mydomain.qsd.NotifyActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_notify" />
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have directly close your `application tag`

Replace this :

```
<application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

by this :

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

**EDIT :**

You have to replace this :

```
<activity
            android:name="com.mydomain.qsd.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

by this :

```
<activity
            android:name="com.mydomain.qsd.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
```

---

This :

```
<activity
            android:name="com.mydomain.qsd.SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

by this :

```
<activity
            android:name="com.mydomain.qsd.SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
```

---

This :

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.mydomain.qsd.gcm.GCMReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" />
```

by this:

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.mydomain.qsd.gcm.GCMReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
```

---

And finally this :

```
<activity
            android:name="com.mydomain.qsd.NotifyActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_notify" />
        </activity>
```

by this :

```
<activity
            android:name="com.mydomain.qsd.NotifyActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_notify" />
```

Comment: Ah.. stupid stupid stupid I am..lol  Silly little mistakes drive you nuts. Not sure if I did that or not because the one I made a copy from is fine and correct. Thanks for that. Accepted

Answer (score 1):

Your application Tag and also Activity tags have self close so remove that

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />  <----- remove /
```